# My @Embedded Component is coming back null through Hibernate when it isn't null in the DB

Tags: java, hibernate, components

I'm running into an issue reconstituting an object from the database using Hibernate.  An `@Embedded` component is throwing a NullPointerException when it's being accessed for the class' `hashCode()` implementation.

The reconstitution is attempting to be done thus:

```
@Override
public Collection<Web> getWebs() {
    Collection<?> dbWebs =
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createQuery("from Web")
        .list();
    Set<Web> webs = new HashSet<Web>();
    for (Object web : dbWebs) {
        webs.add((Web) web);
    }
    return webs;
}
```

And fails at `.list()`.

**UPDATE:** I isolated the failure point to setting the the Shipment property's fetch strategy to `EAGER`.  If it's `LAZY` the items all come out of the DB fine but I need it to be `EAGER` to work with other parts of the app.  Further thoughts?

The parent class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "web")
public class Web {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Embedded
    private WebNumber number;

    @Embedded
    private IcnRange icnRange;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) //Cannot make this EAGER
    @JoinColumn(name = "shipment_id")
    private Shipment shipment

...

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hashcode = 0;
        hashcode += this.getIcnRange().hashCode();
        hashcode += this.getPublicId().hashCode();
        return hashcode;
    }

}
```

IcnRange:

```
@Embeddable
public class IcnRange implements Comparable<IcnRange>, Serializable {

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride(
            name = "number",
            column = @Column(
                             name = "first_icn",
                             length = ICN.FIELD_LENGTH,
                             nullable = false))
    private ICN firstIcn;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride(
            name = "number",
            column = @Column(
                             name = "last_icn",
                             length = ICN.FIELD_LENGTH,
                             nullable = false))
    private ICN lastIcn;

...

    public IcnRange(final IcnRange icnRange) {
        this.firstIcn = new ICN(icnRange.getFirstIcn());
        this.lastIcn = new ICN(icnRange.getLastIcn());
    }
}
```

ICN:

```
@Embeddable
public class ICN implements Comparable<ICN>, Serializable {

    @Column(nullable = false, length = FIELD_LENGTH)
    private String number;

...

}
```

WebNumber:

```
@Embeddable
final class WebNumber implements Serializable {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column (name = "stock_type", nullable = false, length = StockType.FIELD_LENGTH)
    private StockType stockType;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride (
        name = "number",
        column =
            @Column (
                    name = "pallet",
                    nullable = false,
                    length = Pallet.FIELD_LENGTH))
    private Pallet pallet;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column (name = "pallet_id", nullable = false, length = PalletId.FIELD_LENGTH)
    private PalletId palletId;


}
```

The specific offensive line is in the copy constructor:

```
public IcnRange(final IcnRange icnRange) {
    this.firstIcn = new ICN(icnRange.getFirstIcn());
    this.lastIcn = new ICN(icnRange.getLastIcn());
}
```

It chokes upon calling `icnRange.getFirstIcn()`.  Further investigation reveals that `icnRange` enters the method as `null` so for some reason the component is not being reconstituted.  Investigation of the DB reveals that none of the fields are null.  I'm including WebNumber as if I reverse the `hashCode()` method in `Web`, it still fails because `getPublicId()`, which depends on `WebNumber`, returns null

The Full Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot process null arguments.
    at jaci.util.ExceptionUtils.illegalNullArgs(ExceptionUtils.java:20)
    at jaci.model.check.IcnRange.<init>(IcnRange.java:54)
    at jaci.model.web.Web.getIcnRange(Web.java:345)
    at jaci.model.web.Web.hashCode(Web.java:255)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:372)
    at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:200)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:305)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:245)
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.endCollectionLoad(Loader.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:888)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:752)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1881)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3072)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:415)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:905)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:873)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:590)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:412)
    at org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:877)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:752)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at jaci.dao.WebDaoHibernate.getWebs(WebDaoHibernate.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy44.getWebs(Unknown Source)
    at jaci.dao.WebDaoIntegrationTest.getWebs_NoCriteria_OneOrMoreWebs(WebDaoIntegrationTest.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringTestMethod.invoke(SpringTestMethod.java:160)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTestMethod(SpringMethodRoadie.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie$RunBeforesThenTestThenAfters.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:333)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runWithRepetitions(SpringMethodRoadie.java:217)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTest(SpringMethodRoadie.java:197)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:143)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:160)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Any thoughts for a weary sailor?  Thank in advance!

Comment: Would you mind posting the stack trace, just for completeness?

Comment: Can you post ICN class as well?

Comment: Sorry. Should have done that in the first place. :)

Comment: Tim, ever get an answer? I'm running into this as well

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark, but I think Hibernate pulls back embedded objects as null if all their properties are null. Could that be true here? EDIT: I guess this is ancient, but I'm still a little curious if that might have been what happened way back when